# Create one nested object with two objects from dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm not sure if the title of my question is the right description to the issue I'm facing.

I'm reading the following table of data from a spreadsheet and passing it as a dataframe:

```
Name    Description Value
foo     foobar      5
baz     foobaz      4
bar     foofoo      8
```

I need to transform this table of data to json following a specific schema.

I'm trying to get the following output:

```
{'global': {'Name': 'bar', 'Description': 'foofoo', 'spec': {'Value': '8'}}
```

So far I'm able to get the `global` and `spec` objects but I'm not sure how I should combine them to get the expected output above.

I wrote this:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Description'] == 'foofoo':
            global = row.to_dict()
            spec = row.to_dict()

            del(global['Value'])
            del(spec['Name'])
            del(spec['Description'])
            print("global:", global)
            print("spec:", spec)
```

with the following output:

```
global: {'Name': 'bar', 'Description': 'foofoo'}
spec: {'Value': '8'}
```

How can I combine these two objects to get to the desired output?

Comment: Naming a variable `global` is probably a bad idea, be careful!

Comment: yes. I saw this. This is not my real code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you that output:

```
global['spec'] = spec
combined = {'global': global}
```

Comment: The value in a key, value pair can be any object, even another dict. You can assign it just like any other key, value pair (dict["key"] = value). In the first line, the key "spec" is assigned the spec dict as its value. In the second line, a new dict is created with the whole global dict assigned to the key "global".

Comment: Ok. thanks. It's working but seems to be pretty slow.

Comment: @SimonBreton `.iterrows()` is notoriously sluggish, try profiling the program?

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if it works faster: slow speed might be due to iterrows. I suggest you move the iteration to the dictionary after exporting from the dataframe.

```
    Name    Description Value
0   foo foobar  5
1   baz foobaz  4
2   bar foofoo  8

#Export dataframe to dictionar, using the 'index' option
M = df.to_dict('index')

r = {}
q = []

#iterating through the dictionary items(key,value pair)
for i,j in M.items():

    #assign value to key 'global'

    r['global'] = j

    #popitem() works similarly to pop in list,
    #take out the last item
     #and remove it from parent dictionary
     #this nests the spec key, inside the global key

    r['global']['spec'] = dict([j.popitem()])  

    #this ensures the dictionaries already present are not overriden
    #you could use copy or deep.copy to ensure same state

    q.append(dict(r))

{'global': {'Name': 'foo', 'Description': 'foobar', 'spec': {'Value': 5}}}
{'global': {'Name': 'baz', 'Description': 'foobaz', 'spec': {'Value': 4}}}
{'global': {'Name': 'bar', 'Description': 'foofoo', 'spec': {'Value': 8}}}
```

[dict popitem](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem)

Comment: Could you explain a bit?

Comment: added explanation to the answer

Comment: The data set table I've used is an simplified example of my real data set. In my real data set I have a lot more columns. Your solution would work fine except for `popitem()` which is not a very dynamic option. I would need something allowing me to select the columns I want to pass in the spec object.

Comment: @SimonBreton _The data set table I've used is an simplified example of my real data set. In my real data set I have a lot more columns._ The format of the JSON is the same though, right? As in you've got everything under `'global'`, and some data under the `'spec'` key?